# Nonparametric credible intervals

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, credible-interval

I have a small (*n* ≈ 15) IID sample from a continuous distribution that I have no reason to believe (a priori or a posteriori) belongs to a familiar parametric family. I do know a priori that the distribution is bounded, and I know its bounds, but that's about all I know. I'd like to construct 95% credible intervals for the population mean and standard deviation.

I'm at a loss as to how to do this because it appears that credible intervals require a posterior PDF, which requires a likelihood function, which requires a parametric model. The term "nonparametric Bayes" seems to refer to techniques that use a parametric model whose number of parameters is allowed to grow with the sample size. I don't think that's what I want. I can imagine using something like the set of all piecewise linear functions with integral 1 and *n* pieces as a parametric model, but a bit of preliminary work in this direction makes me think it would be very messy.

If what I want here isn't really possible, then what would a conscientious Bayesian do in my situation? Is there perhaps a way to frame the problem so that I can say that I'm 95% sure the population mean is in some 95% *confidence* interval?

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to avoid setting up a full probability model.  With only 15 observations your credible interval will likely to depend on the structure of your likelihood and prior.  Nonparametric Bayesian approaches may be useful, but it's hard to imagine that you're going to do much better than just eyeballing your data and trying to transform it to a reasonable parametric family.

A [Dirichlet Process Mixture](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/281B-spring04/readings/escobar-west.pdf) model of some bounded distribution may be a good starting point.  Alternatively, the model you describe would essentially be a [Bayesian Boostrap](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-9/issue-1/The-Bayesian-Bootstrap/10.1214/aos/1176345338.full).  However the point of that paper is that using the empirical distribution is not a reasonable model for some inferences.

Answer (score 0):

Well, worst comes to worst, there's always Chebyshev's inequality.
$$Pr(|x-E(x)|≥k*\sigma) ≤ \frac{1}{k^2} $$
Similarly, Markov's inequality:
$$Pr(x≥a)≤ \frac{E(x)}{a}$$

Although, since there are bounds and you're a Bayesian, I'm guessing you want something much better. (good)